# Why is Chai throwing a TypeError when posting a Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have the following Chai Http Test:

```
  it("should simulate the API tier filling out a report", (done) => {
    // Send some JSON
    let aReport = {"name": "Jack"};

    chai.request(webapp.app)
    .post('/report')
    .set('content-type', 'application/json')
    .send(aReport)
    .end((err: any, res: any) => {
      expect(err).to.be.null;
      expect(res.body.report).to.be.ok;
      expect(res).to.have.status(200);
      done();
    }).catch( (error) => {
      console.error('ERROR:', error);
      done(error);
      });
  });
```

I'm getting the following error logged when sending:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:555:11)
    at Test.Request.end (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:873:9)
    at node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:72:12
    at Test.then (node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:71:31)
    at Test.exports.catch (node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:81:15)
    at Context.it (test/report.spec.ts:57:13)
```

It's my understand that send's method signature accepts a POJO and will handle proper posting.

**Question:**
Using the above approach, how do i correctly post a JSON object using chai-http?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stack trace, I think that it's the `/report` handler that's causing the error (perhaps it's calling `res.end()` with a numerical argument?), not `chai-http`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was causing request.end() to be called 2x. This occured because while end() offers up a catch() method, the catch() method can only be called after then().

I refactored this using async/await and typescript to the following:

```
it("should simulate the API tier filling out a report", async() => {

let aReport = {"name": "Jack"};

var request = chai.request(webapp.app)
.post('/report')
.set('content-type', 'application/json');

try {
  let res = await request.send(aReport);
  expect(res.body).to.be.ok;
  expect(res.body.id).to.be.ok;
  expect(res).to.have.status(200);
} catch (e) {
  expect(e).to.be.null;
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Removing the catch clause fixed my problem. That is, remove the following clause

```
.catch( (error) => {
  console.error('ERROR:', error);
  done(error);
  });
```